# How can I group objects without losing their glue points?

Tags: diagrams, libreoffice-draw

Suppose I have two objects in LibreOffice Draw: A Foo object and a label object. Now, I want to connect 'smart' connectors to the glue points of Foo's; but I also want to group together Foo's with the labels so that they move around together. Unfortunately, when I do the latter, I lose the (implicit) glue points of the separate Foo's, and my connectors now adhere to the centers of the sides of the bounding rectange - new implicit glue points for the group.

Is there a way - other than manually adding glue points - of keeping the inner object glue points usable when it's grouped as well?

Answer (score 1):

From experiments:  ungroup the objects.  Then use the 'smart' connector to connect the internal glue points.  Then restore the grouping.  Now the connectors are dragged with the moving grouped object.  Round-about, but it's working for me.